# constexpr initializers and enum template arguments

Tags: templates, c++11, enums, constexpr

I'm noticing something strange in my code when I use constexpr initializers and enum template argumets. For example, the following code will compile:

```
enum class TestEnum1 {
    Val1,
    Val2
};

template <TestEnum1 EnumVal> class TestClass1 {
    public:
        constexpr TestClass1() {
        }
};

class TestClass2 {
    public:
        TestClass1<TestEnum1::Val1> TestObject = TestClass1<TestEnum1::Val1>();
};

int main() {
    TestClass2 testObj;
}
```

while the following will not:

```
enum class TestEnum1 {
    Val1,
    Val2
};

template <typename T, TestEnum1 EnumVal> class TestClass1 {
    public:
        constexpr TestClass1() {
        }
};

class TestClass2 {
    public:
        TestClass1<int, TestEnum1::Val1> TestObject = TestClass1<int, TestEnum1::Val1>();
};

int main() {
    TestClass2 testObj;
}
```

note that I only added another template argument before the existing one. The error message is something like:

```
error: 'enum class TestEnum1' is not a class or a namespace
error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Glad if someone would explain why or at least solve the problem. I'm using g++5.3 with --std=c++11 and windows 10.

**EDIT:** I just tested `enum`, under which circumstance errors still occurred, but with the first item on the error list removed. Tested `int` and everything went fine.

Comment: reproduced in g++ 4.9.1 but not clang 3.5.1 or VS 2015, also the `constexpr` seems irrelevant (at least in my testing)

Comment: may I ask why you are initializing the member like that? looks useless to me; the default constructor is called regardless.

Comment: Well I'm trying to implement property wrappers, like GetSetProperty, where I use `std::function`s as getter/setters. It seems most reasonable to me that the getter and setter should be initialized when the property wrapper is created and then never be changed again. The first template parameter is the type of the property and the second is PropertyType::ReadWrite/ReadOnly/WriteOnly.

Comment: I was more asking why you chose the `A a = A()` syntax which `g++` seems to be hung up on. If you want member initialization, you should do `A a {1, 2}` or whatever variables instead of `A a = A(1, 2)`

Comment: I just think that the new syntax is somehow misleading. But sure, this is a nice solution to the problem.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely a compiler bug, I can't reproduce it with g++ 6.1.1 either.

Comment: By the way, `--std=STD` might be accepted by g++ but the correct form is `-std=STD` (single dash).